# Two-words argument in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a problem with a shell script. It is supposed to read arguments: index, date, time1 (the beginning of the interval), time2 (the end of the interval). It should count how many times the user(index) has logged on the given date in the time interval time1-time2.

For example : 121212 "Jan 14" 00 12

This works, but I have a problem with the argument date. It doesn't recognize it as one argument. It splits it in Jan and 14" which is a big problem. I've been searching on the internet for a few hours, but I couldn't find solution anywhere. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read user date time1 time2
list=`last | grep ^$user.*$date | awk '{ print $7 }'`

start=$time1
end=$time2

echo "start $start"
echo "end $end"
count=0
for el in $list ;
do
      login=$el
echo "najava $najava"

checkIf(){
        current=$login
         [[ ($start = $current || $start < $current) && ($current = $end || $current < $end) ]]
}
if checkIf; then
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        ip=`last | grep ^$user.*$date.*$login | awk '{ print $3 }'`
        echo $ip >> address.txt
else
        continue
fi
  done
  echo "The user has logged in $count times in the given time interval"
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but consider reviewing my goto reference on [handling command-line arguments](http://www.shelldorado.com/goodcoding/cmdargs.html). When referencing variables which may contain spaces, you'll want to quote the variables such that is handled as a single string and not individual arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using $1, $2, $3, $4, ... for command line arguments (instead of using read)

Call your script using:

```
./script.sh 121212 "Jan 14" 00 12
```

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason need/want `read` you could say:

```
read -r user mm dd time1 time2

date="$mm $dd"
```

Using `-r` is generally a good idea – even when one *think* one does not need it.

> The -r option to read prevents backslash interpretation (usually used as a backslash newline pair, to continue over multiple lines). Without this option, any backslashes in the input will be discarded. You should almost always use the -r option with read.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Else, if you have control on input you could say:

```
121212 "Jan\ 14" 00 12
```

Then you do *not* use `-r`!